# Cassandra hadoop word count example not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I am trying to run the hadoop examples provided in the cassandra **examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count**. I am using the cassandra-2.0 branch. I have a single node cassandra running locally. I was able to run the **./bin/word_count_setup** step successfully but when I run the **./bin/word_count** step I am getting the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:661)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.<init>(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:297)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader.initialize(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:consistency level LOCAL_ONE not compatible with replication strategy (org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy))
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result$execute_prepared_cql3_query_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:52627)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result$execute_prepared_cql3_query_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:52604)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:52519)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1785)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1770)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:631)
    ... 6 more


----------
```

Has anyone seen this before ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you provide the full link form where you downloaded the examples.

Comment: Hi John, The example I am running is from the cassandra github repo. [examples](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count)